# Why can't ArrayStoreExceptions be caught by the Java compiler?

Tags: java, exception

I understand what an ArrayStoreException is. My question is: why isn't this caught by the compiler?

This might be an odd example, but say you do this:

```
    HashMap[] h = new LinkedHashMap[4];
    h[0] = new PrinterStateReasons();
```

Why can't the compiler recognize that this isn't valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the information you've given the compiler allows what you're doing. It's only the runtime state that's invalid. Your `h` variable is declared as being a `HashMap[]`, which means that as far as `h` is concerned, anything implementing `HashMap` is a valid element. `PrinterStateReasons` implements `HashMap`, and so `h[0] = new PrinterStateReasons();` is a perfectly valid statement. Similarly, since `LinkedHashMap` implements `HashMap`, the statement `HashMap[] h = new LinkedHashMap[4];` is a perfectly valid statement. It's only at *runtime* that you try to store a `PrinterStateReasons` object as an element in a `LinkedHashMap` array, which you can't do as it isn't assignment-compatible.

The two statements you've given are contiguous, but of course the generalized reality is far more complex. Consider:

```
HashMap[] h = foo.getHashMapArray();
h[0] = new PrinterStateReasons();

// ... elsewhere, in some `Foo` class -- perhaps compiled
// completely separately from the code above, perhaps
// even by a completely different team and even a different
// compiler --  and only combined with the code above at runtime...

public HashMap[] getHashMapArray() {
    return new LinkedHashMap[4];
}
```

Comment: So you're saying it only occurs at runtime because at compile time, the reference doesn't yet point to an array of LinkedHashMaps?

Comment: @varatis: There **is** no reference at compile-time. Only type signatures. If you want the compiler to ensure that only `LinkedHashMap`s are stored in `h`, you must declare it as `LinkedHashMap[] h`.

Comment: Ok, so then the compiler doesn't catch it because a LinkedHashMap hasn't yet been stored in the HashMap array? I understand why my code is a legal program, I just don't understand exactly why it can't be checked at compile time. Let me know if what I asked is correct. EDIT: Also, maybe the answer is just that this is not how the compiler is written. Either way, let me know.

Comment: @varatis: Consider my second example. It's entirely possible that the function `getHashMapArray` is coming from a class file compiled completely separately from the code using it. While it's possible the compiler might, with a fair bit of code path analysis, be able to catch *some* of these, since it **cannot** catch them all, there's no point in (dramatically) increasing the compiler complexity having it check for the small number it can catch. It is, at the end of the day, a runtime error -- and so it's caught at runtime. :-) You can make it a compile-time error by declaring `h` differently.

Answer (score 0):

What the compiler can't catch is when you refer to a specific type array using a more generic type array:

```
String[] s = new String[10];
Object[] o = s;
o[0] = new Integer(5);
```

The compiler can't detect it because it has no way, from the variable declaration, to know the actual type of the array.

Note that you won't have this problems with generic collections, because although a String[] is also an Object[], a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`. One more reason to prefer collections over arrays.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't know this class and didn't suspect it was a standard class.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Language Specification says that this is valid program.   A compiler that flagged it as an error is not implementing the specification, and therefore is not a compliant Java compiler.  The real harm of a non-compliant compiler is that it leads to people writing source code that is not portable; e.g. compiles with one compiler but not another.

The best that a compiler could legally do is to *warn* you that the code will always throw an exception.  For instance, *some* compilers will warn you about null pointer exceptions that will always be thrown.  I guess they don't do this in the array index case because the analysis is more complicated, and the mistake is made less often.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose that a smart compiler would be able to statically analyse that h can never be anything else than a LinkedHashmap[] at line 2.

But without that (potentially rather complex analytics, perhaps not this simple case though) the compiler can't really know what is assigned to h. You can assign a PrinterStateReasons to a HashMap, just not to a LinkedHashMap.